# How to verify Biometrics finger with data in smart card in Tactivo mini reader in android

Tags: java, android, smartcard, biometrics

I am currently developing android app that verify biometric figure data from fingureprint reader with enrolled biometric data from smart card.  `PreciseMobileTKAndroid` lib enable verifying biometric fingers with local database and owner database in examples of sdk. But I can't use these approaches because these methods are depending on database for enrolled fingerprints. I also found `PBBiometryVerifier` interface that contains `verifyTemplateSmartcard()` method for verifying data from smart card, if someone has experience in developing with this lib, please help me with example. I have no idea about implementating that interface for custom verification process.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Any answers on this? I am facing the same problem. Thanks